# Spring boot actuaor mix with micrometer for prometheus returnes empty result

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I configured my spring boot application to export Actuator data for prometheus as described in https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-actuator-metrics-monitoring-dashboard-prometheus-grafana/ but unlike document, when I called /actuator/prometheus, an empty page displayed.

Things I did:
- add spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency and check results (/actuator), it worked
- add io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus and check results (/actuator/prometheus) did not work
- change management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: "*", and still /actuator/prometheus did not work
- create a fresh empty project with above configs and /actuator/prometheus worked!

so there is a problem with my project

Answer (score 1):

After whole day research I found there is a class in my project extending from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and a method overriding `configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)` which when I commented method /actuator/prometheus will work correctly

Comment: You can also just not send the "Accept" HTTP header in the request to actuator/prometheus. This way the conversion would not be needed.